# inconsistent shopify front end

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

How do I put titles on the products at the side, below the price of the products?

#### Like this:

[image]

#### Some of the items have this which I don't like

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the customizing options of you each template. There must be an option to change the view except editing the code.

Dashboard > Themes > Customize

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You are using different templates.

So, you need to edit your theme to always use the same template.

I'm assuming there is an IF asking for the custom image-box.

[image: product-alternate]

[image: product]